# How to connect GridDB with Apache Spark for data processing?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, griddb

I have a huge amount of data stored in GridDB and want to process it using Apache Spark. However, I'm unsure how to connect GridDB to Spark or use GridDB as a data source. I have tried modifying the code to connect to a Postgres database, but I need to learn how to modify it to work with GridDB.

I tried modifying the following code to work with GridDB:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object GridDBSparkExample {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("GridDB-Spark").getOrCreate()
.load()
```

However, I am not sure how to modify it to connect to GridDB and use it as a data source in Spark. I am looking for solution or recommendations for using GridDB with Spark.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75724502/how-can-i-use-griddb-with-apache-spark